# Hover event on kendo chart

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-chart

I am using kenod box plot in my project. Is there any way i can get a hover event when the user hovers over the box plot chart? Not the(onserieshover)event ,but on simply hover on chart area?

Help needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add event listener for mouseover event to the div tag of your chart. Please see below example

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="kendoChart></div>
</body>
<script>
 document.getElementById("kendoChart").addEventListener("mouseover",kendoChartMouseOver);

function kendoChartMouseOver()
{
 @* Do Something On Mouse Hover *@
}
</script>
</html>
```

I have not tested the above code but it should work fine.

Comment: Thank you , this is one way we can achieve it, but was thinking/wondering is there a direct way provided by kendo, seems like no :(

Comment: yeah kendo only provides hover for series and not the whole chart.

Comment: This seems the only possible way now :) , Thanks